# Java 8 - Filter list inside map value

Tags: java, iterator, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am writing a method which takes an input `Map` of the form `Map<Term, List<Integer>>` where a `Term` is defined [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Term.html).

Method:

1. Go over the keys of the `Map` and filter them using a `Term` attribute.
2. For each of the remaining keys, get the size of the corresponding list, cap it to 5 (`min(List.size(), 5)`) and add the output to a global var (say, `totalSum`)
3. Return `totalSum`

This is what I have written so far:

```
 inputMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().field().equals(fieldName))    // Keep only terms with fieldName
    .forEach(entry -> entry.getValue()
        .map(size -> Math.min(entry.getValue().size(), 5)))   // These 2 lines do not work
        .sum();
```

I am unable to take as input a stream of lists, output an integer for each of those lists and return the sum of all the outputs.

I can obviously write it using for loops, but I am trying to learn Java 8 and was curious if this problem is solvable using it.

Comment: The `Map` interface now has its own `forEach()` method that takes a `BiConsumer` instance.  This can be used to simplify your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the `forEach` method. You can `map` each entry of the `Map` to an `int`, and `sum` those integers :

```
int sum = inputMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().field().equals(fieldName))
    .mapToInt(entry -> Math.min(entry.getValue().size(), 5))
    .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), the following will work using [MutableMap](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/map/MutableMap.html) and [IntList](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/IntList.html).

```
MutableMap<Term, IntList> inputMap =
    Maps.mutable.of(term1, IntLists.mutable.of(1, 2, 3), 
                    term2, IntLists.mutable.of(4, 5, 6, 7));

long sum = inputMap
    .select((term, intList) -> term.field().equals(fieldName))
    .sumOfInt(intList -> Math.min(intList.size(), 5));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

The forEach invocation terminates the stream. You can use map directly without forEach.